# What does abbreviation $ecnd$ represent in the book "Real variable and Integration" of the author $ John \ Benedetto$?

Tags: measure-theory, terminology

In John Benedetto's text: "Real variable and Integration", he refers to a property of functions which he calls "ecnd". This doesn't seem to be a universal definition, probably his 
own. It occurs early in the text but I cannot find a definition. Can someone clarify what this may mean?

**Note:**

Here $\text{ecnd}$ means everywhere continuous nowhere differentiable functions. One such example is  $f(x)=\sum \frac{1}{k^2} \sin (k^2 \pi x)$.

See section $1.3.2$,  $ \ Sets \ \ of \ \ differentiability \ $  of the above book. (pages from $25-27$)

Comment: If there is no definition, could you please give the context?

Comment: The table of contents at https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780817643065#toc suggests the book has multiple indices. Is "ecnd" not in any index?

Comment: ["everywhere continuous nowhere differentiable"](https://books.google.it/books?id=o928IAmynmoC&pg=PA21).

Comment: https://books.google.ca/books?id=bDXvAAAAMAAJ&q=ecnd&dq=ecnd&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBmN-5y7vgAhVLb60KHcOcCzYQ6AEINTAC

Comment: @postmortes, yes I know that my edited title is different from the body but it is also true that the user $\text{David Dyer}$ hopefully got his answer from my correction because I saw the mentioned book.

Comment: Paul Halmos, a great writer of mathematics, used to say that (as in the case of this book) when dealing with a definition that has not appeared in a very long time, the author should always remind the reader of said definition or, at least, point out where in the same book the definition is to be found.

Answer (score 1):

According to the index of notations, it is defined in Section 1.3.2 of the said book:
[image]